# Got "error 2" in tesseract-ocr

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

I've been running [tesseract-ocr](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) in a Java application using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), and, in some files, I got a error with the code 2. I don't know what it means or what I can do to fix it.

I use the last version of tesseract (3.01) in a debian 6, with kernel 2.6.32.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get this figured out?

Comment: How do you keep the error from killing your app? When I get the error, my JRE completely crashes (as it is a FATAL Error), and I have to restart my app. How are you working around this crash?

Comment: I not working in this code anymore... but, if I remember well, a try-catch block... but not sure...